# StringBuilder и метод .split

Tags: java

Как мне вывести из StringBuilder , мой Вывод: [Ljava.lang.String;@33909752

input:

```
java python c++ kotlin php sql http css javascript r go
```

output:

```
java
python
kotlin
php
javascript
```

Вот мой код:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         String str;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while(sc.hasNext()){
      //java python c++ kotlin php sql http css javascript r go
        str = sc.nextLine();
        builder.append(str.toString().split(" "));
        
       // String result = builder;
        System.out.println(builder);

      }
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(builder.toString());`

Comment: Вообще, если каждый элемент с новой строки нужно вывести, то нужно либо в билдер после каждого элемента добавлять перенос строки, либо после сплита соединить через `String.join()` с указанием переноса строки в качестве разделителя (без билдера вообще)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            //java python c++ kotlin php sql http css javascript r go
            str = sc.nextLine();
            String[] strings = str.split(" ");
            for (String string : strings) {
                builder.append(string)
                        .append("\n");
            }

            System.out.println(builder);
        }

    }
```

Или так:

```
str = sc.nextLine().replace(" ", "\n");
```

Comment: массив нельзя ! еще не дошли по курсу

Comment: @sstwg, тогда и split вам нельзя использовать, потому что он массив возвращает

Comment: можно сделать  sc.nextLine().replace(" ", "\n"); тогда не надо использовать StringBuilder

Comment: сработало, ставь код зачту ;)

Comment: там даже без массива можно, вообщем работает и без массива и for! thx

Answer (score 1):

Вариант без массива и цикла for.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         String str;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while(sc.hasNext()){
      //java python c++ kotlin php sql http css javascript r go
        str = sc.nextLine().replace(" ", "\n");
        builder.append(str.toString());
        System.out.println(builder);

      }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   while (sc.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(sc.nextLine().replace(" ", "\n"));
   }

}
```

имхо так проще. Зачем лишние сущности, когда они не используются?

Comment: Тему задачи внимательно прочитай ;)

Comment: да я читаю, так задачи надо ставить такие, где использование подобных вещей оправдано,  а не городите лес, просто чтоб был. имхо Просто глас рассудка, я видел принятый ответ :) @sstwg

Comment: А не думал, что может этот кусочек кода быть куском большего кода или задачи?

Comment: @sstwg тогда и надо писать эту задачу или указывать, что это кусок реального кода. У нас вроде как сообщество свободное, и я волен выражать свое мнение. Или нет?

Comment: Все хорошо, пишем код.